# How to do a graphic behaviour with no specific parameters

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to investigate about torque motors and I want to do a graphic showing its behaviour depending different parameters. My problem is that I don't want to do it with some specific parameters.

For example, first with 190Kv, 15V and different values of the power, then with the same 190Kv, but 16V and another time some values of power, etc.

This kind of graphics has a name? How can I have to do this? Because do this for 10 motors that you have the specifications is easy to excel. But if I don't have it, I really don't know how doing it.

Maybe if you can say something then I can search more information, because I don't know how to start it.

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

You might try an animation, where each frame corresponds to a different value of one parameter, and could show several curves for different values of a second parameter.  Something like this:

[image]